# Don't sort Tablesorter when TH child is clicked

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a "Select All" checkbox in a TH.  I want to be able to sort that particular column, but not when interacting with the checkbox/input that is in the TH.

```html
<th data-sorter="checkboxes">
  <span>Attended</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="selectAll" name="selectAll" value="Y">
</th>
```

Is this possible.  I'm sure I could pull the checkbox outside of the TH and use CSS positioning and zoom properties to "place" it on top of the TH, but I want to avoid that.

Thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 0):

If you're using my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), it automatically ignores interactions with form elements inside of the header cell. Or, you can add a class of `tablesorter-noSort` to the element (set by the [`cssNoSort` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssnosort)) and any clicks inside of it will be ignored.

If you're using the original tablesorter (v2.0.5), then you'll need to unbind the `click` event on the header cell, and add a custom click event that will ignore events inside the form element.